How can I unit-test computations that happen in a monadic transformer stack with an IO base layer?
Below is very simplified version of a program I wrote¹, where I have some read-only state (e.g. screen size, etc) made available via ReaderT, and some mutable state (the state of the game) that I interact with via the StateT layer. Unfortunately, I need MonadIO, mostly for printing to screen and to generate random numbers.
module Main where

import MTLPrelude
import System.Random

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let s0 = "inital state"
  let env = "read-only env"
  sEnd <- computation `execStateT` s0 `runReaderT` env
  print sEnd

computation :: (MonadIO m,
                MonadState String m,
                MonadReader String m)
            => m ()
computation = do
  e <- ask
  s <- get
  i <- liftIO $ randomRIO (0 :: Int, 10)
  put $ s ++ e ++ show i

(In the real case, computation layers not only a MonadState and MonadReader, but also MonadWriter and MaybeT; see link at the bottom of the question for full code.)
I have managed to break computation in ((some >>= distinct >>= logical) <* actions >>= chained >> together)
Luckily some of them don't need MonadIO, so they can be easily tested; others only need MonadIO, e.g. one bit just sleeps for a fraction of a second; but those are the less complex one, so there's not even much to test.
The more complex actions, instead, do rely on MonadIO plus some other layer (one or more of those I mentioned), which I have exemplified in the snippet above by using randomRIO, which makes them not testable (not as easily as I would do with pure functions via QuickCheck, at least).
How can I rewrite the above code, or rething the whole approach, so that I can make functions more testable?
Further thoughts:

One approach I initially thought of is that I could use reader layer to pass relevant IO actions, e.g. putStr and randomRIO, down the stack, but this would probably not help me achieve anything, because actually performing those actions would still require the whole stack to be powered with IO (explicitly or via MonadIO constraint). For instance, I could change the above code to this:
-- same imports
main :: IO ()
main = do
  let s0 = "inital state"
  let env = "read-only env"
  sEnd <- computation `execStateT` s0 `runReaderT` (env, randomRIO)
  print sEnd

computation :: (MonadIO m,
                MonadState String m,
                MonadReader (String, (Int,Int) -> IO Int) m)
            => m ()
computation = do
  (e, io) <- ask
  s <- get
  i <- liftIO $ io (0 :: Int, 10)
  put $ s ++ e ++ show i

but I still have liftIO and MonadIO around, so testing would still require that I write some IO action that mocks the real one.

Then I thought that maybe the ideal would be to swap the IO used by the real program to print characters to change the state of the screen, with State String, where the String would represent the screen.



I am aware of this thread, but I don't consider it a duplicate because I'm asking about a more specific scenario than in that question, where there's no mention of transformers stacks.

(¹) It's the game Snake, which I'm doing as an excuse to approach game development in Haskell. Here is the repo, in case you want to give a look, even just to better contextualize my question above.

@willeM_VanOnsem, no, MonadReader _ _ and MonadState _ _ are constraints. But yeah, computation's type in the first snippet resolves to StateT String (ReaderT String IO) (). Is that what you meant? Or have I misunderstood your point?

aarggh yes, I read it the wrong way. Somehow got a bit confused.

Perhaps you could make MonadRandom and MonadPrint classes that could be instantiated with something pure for testing.

@DanielWagner, that would be the approach suggested by this answer, right?

@Enlico More or less, yep.
